# Apexcharts custom datalabel issue

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I am using Apexcharts (version 3.26.3) on Angular 8. I am trying to draw a stacked bar chart using custom data label. But it seems the formatter function is not working properly. The code is provided below for better understanding.

```
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        offsetX: 2,
        offsetY: -50,
        formatter: function(value, {seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}){
            if(seriesIndex == 1){
                const visited = totalVisitedCount[dataPointIndex];
                const planned = totalPlannedCount[dataPointIndex];
                let percentage = null;
                if(planned != 0){
                    percentage = Math.floor((visited / planned) * 100) + '%';
                }
                return percentage;
            }
            else{
                return '';
            }
        },
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Muli, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 700,
            colors: ['#000000']
        },
    }
```

As it's a stacked bar, setting `'enabled: true'` shows the data label for both portions of the column. So, I had to do some modifications and display the data label only for the top portion. But surprisingly, for some columns, the formatter is not returning any value even if the percentage variable has calculated values. What could be the problem?

Comment: Without a full running example I can't say much; please consider making something like the code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgLcqx3j/) that is based on a standard apexcharts examples and includes parts of your code.

Comment: I can see two small issues: 1) the `offsetY: -50` (why -50?) is huge for most screen resolutions -- I suspect you don't get a datalabel in some cases because it is just out of canvas. 2) when `planned == 0` `formatter` returns `null`, which results in a datalabel that shows the string `null` which is pobably not what you expected.